# Access to an optional attribute type of a typescript object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class :

```
 class Target {
  ...
  readonly overlay: {
    type: 'none'
   } | {
    type: 'centering',
    style?: {
      color?: string,
      offset?: number,
      size?: number,
    }
   } | {
    type: 'entering',
    style?: {
      color?: string,
      offset?: number,
      direction?: 'up' | 'down',
      angle?: number,
      size?: number
    }
  };
  ...
 }
```

I have an abstract class :

```
 abstract class AbstractParams<TParam> {
  ...
  param: TParam
  ...
 }
```

From this abstract class, I need to define specific classes for all
style attribute within the overlay depending on the `type` attribute value ('centering','entering').

So what I need to do is:

```
type CenteringStyleType = // Type of style attribute within overlay when its attribute `type` equals to `centering`.

class CenteringParams extends AbstractParams<CenteringStyleType> {
 // Here the param attribute would have type:  { color?: string, offset?: number, size?: number }
 // And then I can use it
}
```

And the same for entering:

```
type EnteringStyleType = // Type of style attribute within overlay when its attribute `type` equals to `entering`.

class EnteringParams extends AbstractParams<EnteringStyleType> {
 // Here the param attribute would have type:  { color?: string, offset?: number, size?: number }
}
```

More precisely, EnteringStyleParams and CenteringStyleParams objects will provide a `style` to a Target Object, that's why I need them to have the same `style` definition.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your goal is. I don't get what `Target` is and what you are trying to do with it. Is your goal just to access the corresponding properties inside `overlay.style` depending on what the value of `overlay.type` is?

Comment: Yes, it is ! And Target is the class inside which is the overlay attribute. I try to access what you mentionned into another class

Comment: And by access you mean you want to access it at runtime or that you want to define a type for it? I don't understand what your goal with the line `type CenteringOffset = Target['offset']` is. Can you explain that in more detail? If `Target` is the class holding the `overlay` property, what is `Target['offset']`? You never defined that.

Comment: I need to access to the type of the `style` attribute within the overlay attribute of the class Target, depending on the value of the `type` property.
I need to access this type to use it as a generic type to build another class.
`Target['offset']` is just a try, and it gives the type of the `offset` attribute, so I thought I was on the right way to reach my goal but it seems not

Comment: The comment you posted as an answer only adds to my confusion. You define a type and then define a generic with the same name. This is not how it works. Do you need a generic that extends the type you're looking for? Please consider editing you answer to add a valid example of what you're trying to do. I feel like I could solve you're problem but I still don't fully understand what you're looking for.

Also, what might make the whole thing easier is defining interfaces for `CenteringOverlay` and `EnteringOverlay` and have `type Overlay = CenteringOverlay | EnteringOverlay | ...`.

Comment: I modified my answer, hope it's more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achive this is to explicitly define the types you need instead of typing `Target.overlay` inline. This way you can use them both in the overlay and as the generics. Your code could look something like this:

```
interface CenteringStyleType {
  type: 'centering',
  style?: {
    color?: string,
    offset?: number,
    size?: number,
  }
}

interface EnteringStyleType { /* ... */ }
interface NoneStyleType { /* ... */ }

class Target {
  readonly overlay: CenteringStyleType | EnteringStyleType | NoneStyleType;
}

class CenteringParams extends AbstractParams<CenteringStyleType['style']> { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Now for insane hard-mode veteran difficulty, make color another type. CenteringStyleType['style']['color'] would result in 'property color does not exist on type' -- SO FRUSTRATING